# Los assert en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Por más que busco en Google resultados en español, no aparecen y no logró entender que son los assert. ¿Qué función tienen en NodeJS?

Me pica esa curiosidad ante todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función o módulo assert se suele utilizar en todos los lenguajes que la tienen para comprobar que el contenido que se le está pasando a la función es verdadero y salir del programa o lanzar un error en caso contrario.

En el caso de NodeJS el módulo [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) define una serie de funciones (assert(), assert.deepEqual(), assert.doesNotThrow()...) que pueden ser usadas en tu código para realizar comprobaciones, por ejemplo assert.throws() y assert.doesNotThrow() comprueban que la función evaluada con esos parámetros lanza una determinada excepción, o no lo hace, respectivamente. Las diferentes funciones de este módulo te permiten hacer comprobaciones mas o menos complejas.

¿Cuando querrías utilizar asserts? En general los asserts son usados en los tests, dado que permiten comprobar que ciertas condiciones se han cumplido y te permiten mostrar mensajes personalizados.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me hacía falta esa extensa explicación.